# Magento2: _merge_after event

Tags: magento2, event-observer

I am researching about events and observers and I have a question about this event

When is this event launched and what is it for?

**_merge_after**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can see the merge quote event:

[\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote::merge()](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Quote/Model/Quote.php#L2311)

This will create the new quote. We can use this event when we want to set some values to the new quote.

[\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session::loadCustomerQuote()](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Checkout/Model/Session.php#L337)

```
        if ($this->getQuoteId()) {
            $this->quoteRepository->save(
                $customerQuote->merge($this->getQuote())->collectTotals()
            );
        }
```

[EDIT]

If we work on Magento EE, we can see some cases(Reward Points, Customer Balance) which used this event.

Comment: for example when add a customer to the quote?

Comment: We can add more info to new quote after merging quote.

Comment: i need observe when a customer is added to a quote. For example you are not logged and create a car, then  you login and append customer and quote. I  need observe that.

Comment: I have just updated my answer more details.

Comment: Did it mean it used when add any product in Quote ? or Quote is there and if we merge any new product with that Quote ? or something else which i missed ?

Comment: AFAIK, when logging in: `vendor/magento/module-checkout/etc/frontend/events.xml`.